# From C++ buffer to python::boost::list

Tags: c++, python, boost, python-3.3

I am trying to convert a C++ buffer to a python::boost::list, my C++ class is:

```
#include "boost/python/list.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

class Buffer {
public:
    unsigned char* m_pBuff;
    int m_iWidth;
    int m_iHeight;


    Buffer( cont int p_iWidth, const int p_iHeight ) {
        m_pBuff = new unsigned char[p_iWidth * p_iHeight];

        m_iWidth  = p_iWidth;
        m_iHeight = p_iHeight;
    }

    ~Buffer() { delete[] m_pBuff; }

    /* Class Functions */

    list getList ( void ) {
        list l;
        l.append(m_iWidth);
        l.append(m_iHeight);

        std::string data(m_iWidth * m_iHeight, ' ');

        unsigned char* pBuff = m_pBuff;
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_iWidth * m_iHeight; ++i, ++pBuff ) {
            data[i] = (char*) *pBuff;
        }

        l.append(data);

        return l;
    }
};
```

And the python boost module is defined as:

```
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(BufferMethods)
{

    class_<Buffer>("Buffer", init<const int, const int>()) 
        .add_property("width", &Buffer::m_iWidth)
        .add_property("height", &Buffer::m_iHeight)
        /* Other functions */
        .def("getList", &Buffer::getList)
    ;
}
```

But when I run the module in python it return this error:

```
>>> from BufferMethods import *
>>> Buff = Buffer(800, 600)
>>> dataList = Buff.getList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>>>
```

What I am doing wrong?? I am using python 3.3.

Comment: So it's `boost::python::list`, not `python::boost::list`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to append items into a `boost::python::list` instance, the python type of the appended item is determined from the type of the C++ object given as the argument. Since your `data` is of type `std::string`, this append operation is attempting to create a Python string. Speculation: I guess python strings need to adhere to some layout, and since you're simply feeding it some random data, it fails to interpret it as a valid string, that's why you get a [UnicodeDecodeError](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError). I don't know what exactly you intend to do with the list, and how you would like to expose your buffer to Python, but the following seems to work (using a `std::vector<char>` as the type of `data` instead of `std::string`):

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::python;

class Buffer {
public:
    unsigned char* m_pBuff;
    int m_iWidth;
    int m_iHeight;


    Buffer( const int p_iWidth, const int p_iHeight ) {
        m_pBuff = new unsigned char[p_iWidth * p_iHeight];

        m_iWidth  = p_iWidth;
        m_iHeight = p_iHeight;
    }

    ~Buffer() { delete[] m_pBuff; }

    /* Class Functions */

    list getList ( void ) {
        list l;
        l.append(m_iWidth);
        l.append(m_iHeight);

        std::vector<char> data(m_iWidth*m_iHeight);

        unsigned char* pBuff = m_pBuff;
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_iWidth * m_iHeight; ++i, ++pBuff ) {
            data[i] = (char) *pBuff;
        }

        l.append(data);

        return l;
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(BufferMethods)
{

    class_<std::vector<char> >("CharVec")
            .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<char> >());


    class_<Buffer>("Buffer", init<const int, const int>()) 
        .add_property("width", &Buffer::m_iWidth)
        .add_property("height", &Buffer::m_iHeight)
        /* Other functions */
        .def("getList", &Buffer::getList)
    ;
}
```

So in python (3.2):

```
In [1]: from BufferMethods import *

In [2]: Buff = Buffer(800,600)

In [3]: dataList = Buff.getList()

In [4]: dataList[2]
Out[4]: <BufferMethods.CharVec at 0x18172d0>

In [5]: dataList[2][2]
Out[5]: '\x00'
```

Comment: With your proposal I get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class std::vector<char,class std::allocator<char> >

Comment: @Marcus how did you get this error? Did you copy-paste my code as it is, or did you merge it with yours? It sounds like you forgot to add the part that exposes `std::vector<char>` in `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(BufferMethods)`

Comment: Yes, you were right!! :D I didn't expose std::vector<char>! Thanks! I wondering if I can use this method to create a PhotoImage (tkinter) ... to show an image... maybe using PIL ...

Comment: I never tried this, but if that's your intention, try to find a C API for PIL. Such an API would probably let you receive/create PIL objects in C, access their buffers and do all kinds of modifications. I'd be surprised if such an API didn't exist, after all, the developers need it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved using Python 2.7 ... maybe the error is caused because I am using the unofficial build python.boost from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: I think it's caused because there's a major difference between the handling of strings in python2.x and python3.x

Comment: Maybe this is the reason of why opencv is not ported to python 3.x

Comment: Maybe... I'm not an expert in python, I just use it for scripting my C++ programs. But I know that there are significant, nonbackwards-compatible differences between python2.x and python3.x, so the reason could be something else as well. In the end it's not trivial to port between the two.